# JavaMail-Crypto s/mime error

Tags: java, security, email, encryption, jakarta-mail

So what I'm trying to do is to send an encrypted email to a certain recipient. My method is using the JavaMail-Crypto api and using S/MIME as the encryption method. I tried to test their  [example](http://javamail-crypto.sourceforge.net/examples/EncryptMessage.java).  Btw I didn't copy the PGP codes since I won't use it.

When running it, this error appeared "java.security.NoSuchProviderException: No provider configured for S/MIME".

I googled the error one of the guides told me to just add them to the class path which I already did. I'm currently using the following jars:
bcmail-jdk15on-150
bcprov-jdk15on-150
javamail-crypto_060622
javamail-crypto-bouncycastle-smime

I hope someone can help me on this one. Thanks another question is I'm wondering what these lines of code mean:

```
    char[] smimePw = new String("hello world").toCharArray();
    EncryptionKeyManager smimeKeyMgr = smimeUtils.createKeyManager();
        smimeKeyMgr.loadPublicKeystore(new FileInputStream(new File(
                "./id.p12")), smimePw);

    java.security.Key smimeKey = smimeKeyMgr.getPublicKey("Eric's Key");
```

Thanks in advance,
Jet

Answer (score 0):

use jdk16-1.46.jar instead bcmail-jdk15on-150

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
        <version>1.46</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcmail-jdk16</artifactId>
        <version>1.46</version>
    </dependency>
```